# How can i record multiple windows with segregated audio on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, scripts, google-chrome, audio-recording, video-recording

I want to record multiple windows running on my desktops. For example, let's say I want to record two videos running on two different chrome tabs which are on same/different window. How can I do that? I have seen obs but it doesn't segregate the audio of two different windows so it's of no use. Chrome extensions suck in quality.
Note: **The main problem here is to segregate the audio from different tabs.**
Any script or software anyone can recommend to me.

Thanks